# Is Three.js Web Worker compatible? importScripts("three.js") gives error

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, compatibility, web-worker

It complains on importScripts("three.js"):

```
 Uncaught ReferenceError: window is not defined:
 for ( var x = 0; x < vendors.length && !window.requestAnimationFrame; ++ x ) {
```

And it seems like a hassle to remove everything in three.js that refers to the window object, or is there no other way?

I need to create large amount of geometry+objects during rendering on several cores and I don't want main thread to freeze while doing so.

Answer (score 1):

If you use this code in a webworker you have to remember that a webworker doesn't have access to the window object.

Look for more info [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/#toc-gettingstarted).